# My PL/SQL procedure exception doesn't seem to work

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have a database with continents and I wanted to create a procedure that added a new continent to the database, with exceptions. I tried executing the procedure inside my package GEST_GEO by creating an already existing continent (Asia) and my exception was not raised. Does anyone have any idea that to why it doesn't work ? (nom is name)

Here is my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE GEST_GEO AS
Procedure ADDCONTINENT(pnom continent.nom%TYPE, psuperficie continent.superficie%TYPE);
END GEST_GEO;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY GEST_GEO AS

-- ADDCONTINENT

Procedure ADDCONTINENT(pnom CONTINENT.NOM%TYPE, psuperficie CONTINENT.SUPERFICIE%TYPE) IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CONTINENT VALUES (pnom, psuperficie);
COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The continent already exists');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLCODE || '–' || SQLERRM);

END ADDCONTINENT;
END GEST_GEO;
/


execute GEST_GEO.ADDCONTINENT('Asia',99380);
```

When executing it it just tells me `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` presumes that there's a primary or unique key, or unique index enforced on that column. If there's none, Oracle doesn't know that there's anything "duplicated" so it inserts a row.

Therefore, create something of previously mentioned (keys/indexes).

---

Here's an example: table first (note the primary key constraint in line #2):

```
SQL> create table continent
  2    (nom         varchar2(30) constraint pk_cont primary key,
  3     superficie  number
  4    );

Table created.
```

Procedure: note

- line #5 - always include target column names in `INSERT` statement
- exception handler section: don't *output* the message - unless tool you use supports it, buffer's contents won't be visible to anyone. `RAISE` the error instead
- don't commit within the procedure; let the caller decide whether to commit or not

So:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure addcontinent
  2    (pnom continent.nom%type, psuperficie continent.superficie%type)
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    insert into continent (nom, superficie) values (pnom, psuperficie);
  6  exception
  7    when dup_val_on_index then
  8      raise_application_error(-20001, 'The continent already exists');
  9    when others then
 10      raise;
 11  end addcontinent;
 12  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec addcontinent('Asia', 99380);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec addcontinent('Asia', 99380);
BEGIN addcontinent('Asia', 99380); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: The continent already exists
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.ADDCONTINENT", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL> select * from continent;

NOM                            SUPERFICIE
------------------------------ ----------
Asia                                99380

SQL>
```

Comment: I see! What do you mean by creating keys? Is there another way like for example writing my own exception?

Comment: "What do you mean by creating keys"  - create a primary key on your CONTINENT table.  But gee, there are only 5 continents (well 6 or 7 if you count Australia and Greenland).  Do you really need a procedure to do this?  How many times would that procedure be called, to justify that effort?  Also, dbms_output.put_line just writes to a buffer.  It is up the client program to process and display that buffer.  In sqlplus, SET SERVEROUTPUT ON before calling the procedure.

Comment: It is an exersise, this was asked by my professor so I don't really know if I can add a primary key. That's why I wanted to know if there is another solution

Comment: " I don't really know if I can add a primary key."  So why can't you ask your professor what the limits are?  Never be afraid to ask for more information.  And that goes double (or more) when you get an actual job.  Don't just roll over for unclear requirements.

Comment: I edited the answer, trying to illustrate what I meant. Have a look.

Comment: Another curse of action. Just add the PK, don't ask. Perhaps your instructor is wants to see if you are putting everything together to solve a problem. When you are in the field, you will not be spoon feed the information, especially design issues, it will be your responsibility to get.  But @EdStevens is right, **do not stop asking questions until you fully understand**.

Comment: @Belayer - You make a good point that, absent specifics, the instructor is (hopefully!) looking to see _how_ the student solves the problem.  And conversly, in an actual job situation, the developer/dba should be identifying and actually pushing back against "requirements" that specify _how_ something is done.  Specs should specify _what_ and not get into the weeds of specific implementation.

Comment: Apparently the primary keys were already defined, your code worked. Thank you all